# Does the (USA) English metaphor "Unable to see the forest for the trees" keep its meaning if translated verbatim into Japanese?

Tags: usage, translation, business-japanese, culture

The phrase "Unable to see the forest for the trees" implies one is too entangled in a situation to understand what is transpiring from a larger context, and thus, unable to determine the correct course of action.

I'd like to know whether a native Japanese hearer:
 1. told this phrase in Japanese would interpret it to have the same meaning?
 2. would accept the word 森 to mean a very large amount of information?

Comment: The non-verbatim translation for those curious: 「彼は細部［ささいなこと］にこだわって大局を見ていない。」 Source: http://eow.alc.co.jp/see+forest+trees/UTF-8/?ref=sa

Comment: What would be your verbatim translation?

Comment: @Jeshii 「木を見て森を見ず」, though I can't say definitively if that will be understood by a native Japanese speaker as the same meaning

Comment: It's not a cliché, it is a figure of speech, or a proverb, or possibly a metaphor.

Comment: @onteria_: I know this is the most common translation, but it's actually not a verbatim translation, since it says "Sees the tree(s), doesn't see the forest." A truly verbatim translation would be 木々のため森が見えず。 But the saying about the trees and the forest exists in many languages, and its a bit different in each of them.

Comment: Japanese has alot of the same proverbs as we do in America, with the same meaning.  The only one i know off the top of my head that doesn't have the same meaning is "a rolling stone gathers no moss"  Where in america it means it is good keep moving, in japan, moss is seen as a good thing and thus being still is better.

Comment: @Kdansky, isn't it overused? Please suggest other phrases in English that convey the same meaning that are more frequently used.

Comment: @Huperniketes: Got it covered.

Comment: @Ignacio, I'm going to roll it back because I'm not convinced it isn't a cliché.

Comment: If you like, but the word you want is "idiom".

Comment: No, cliché works well; metaphor would be more appropriate than idiom; and english.se would be a more appropriate site to quibble over the correct English word to use.

Comment: I heard that the Japanese phrase 木を見て森を見ず was originally introduced as a translation of the English phrase “cannot see the forest for the trees.”  Although several webpages make the same claim or similar claims (using other European languages than English), I cannot find a more authoritative source claiming it.  If anyone knows whether this is true or not, I am interested to hear.  Boaz explained in his comment that the Japanese phrase does not literally correspond to the English phrase, which I think suggests against this claim.

Comment: About whether the English phrase in question is a cliché (=an stereotyped expression) or an idiom (a phrase which means something other than its literal meaning): If you want to claim that it is a cliché, you certainly can do so.  But if you make a claim, you have to be prepared for the possibility of being objected.  If you do not want a discussion whether it is a cliché or not, it is unwise to use the word cliché in the first place.  I think that calling it an idiom is neutral, but if you do not agree, you can use “phrase” or “expression” which is hopefully not controversial at all.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi, I used the word *cliché* because its use in the US **is** clichéd. Moreover, the issue of whether *cliché* was the correct word to use in my question bears no relevance to the answers given. The word which most caused debate that affected the answers is *verbatim*. So there was **no** valid reason to strike *cliché* from my question.

Comment: You are missing the point of my comment.  Your use of the word “cliché” _actually caused_ an irrelevant debate, and I think that it was unwise.  You could have avoided this unnecessary argument by simply avoiding claiming that it was a cliché.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi, I realized your point and I don't disagree with your premise. However, if those who wish to be considered *experts* in this subject edit *?* s, they need to edit so as to increase relevancy to the site. Whether usage of an English expression has become a cliché is irrelevant to its meaning in Japanese, which is the point of my *?* and all I was looking for.

Comment: (1) Please do not use the nonstandard abbreviation “?” for the word “question.”  It took me a while to understand that.  (2) I did not edit your question, but I think that Ignacio’s edit increased relevance of the question to this website by removing the controversial and irrelevant statement in your original question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In my 故事ことわざ辞典、「木を見て森を見ず」　is from English phrase "You cannot see the woods for the trees".

[image]

And regarding plural form, 「木」　can mean many trees in Japanese, since Japanese grammar does not always have plural form.

And also In 国語辞典、explanation of 「木を見て森を見ず」 is

> 一本一本の木に目を奪われて全体の森を見ない意から

using 一本一本の木, which means each tree instead of 一本の木 (one tree).

So, 「木を見て森を見ず」 might be verbatim translation of "Unable to see the forest for the trees" in Japanese.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen somewhere a saying (Confucian?), like "looking but not seeing, hearing but not listening".  I want to say it's something like 「見るといえども視ず、聞くといえども聴かず」, although I can't for the life of me find it right now.  But maybe the first part could kind of be applicable.

Answer (score 0):

I would say yes, but I'm not native. (><;

http://www.ymknu200719.com/kotowaza/koto-ki-0026.html